# Full Calendar If no events for a particular month the calendar will automatically load on next month

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is there any way I can make full calendar to automatically proceed to next month if there is no event coming in a particular month.

Say there is no Event in June or the event is already finished, the calendar will proceed to July without click the next month button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used full calendar (or it was years ago) so I may be a bit wrong, but I flew through their docs and this is what I found (btw: their api is rather a weak part of this plugin, speed and efficiency as well but it's your choice).

There is an event in docs that triggers every time the view change, so although the view will be rendered, skipping will be probably not visible. First of all you will have to implement your own methods to move across calendar, because you have to know if you are going forward or backward ([example](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-api-buttons-demo)). So according to this you can try it as such: https://codepen.io/prowseed/pen/bKQEov?editors=0010

```
var lastOperationFlag;
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [...],
    header: false, // don't display the default header
    viewRender: function (view, element) {
      var start = view.start._i; // timestamp of the beginning of current view
      var end = view.end._i; // timestamp of the end of current view
      var events = view.options.events; // all events
      if( checkBoundariesAndCurrentRange(start, end, events) ){
        (lastOperationFlag === 'next') ? $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next') : $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
      }
    }
  });

  $('#prev').on('click', function() {
    lastOperationFlag = 'prev';
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev'); // request previous view
  });

  $('#next').on('click', function() {
    lastOperationFlag = 'next';
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next'); // request next view
  });

  function checkBoundariesAndCurrentRange (start, end, events) {
    if (events.length === 0) return false;
    var smallestDate = null;
    var biggestDate = null;
    var eventsInRange = false;
    events.forEach(e => {
      var ev_start = (new Date(e.start)).getTime(); // !!!!! MORE SAFE to transform it with a momentjs
      // here you can eventually also handle event.end if exists with additional logic
      if (smallestDate == null || ev_start < smallestDate) smallestDate = ev_start;
      if (biggestDate == null || ev_start > biggestDate) biggestDate = ev_start;
      if (start <= ev_start && end >= ev_start) eventsInRange = true; // set the flag if there is at least one event in given start-end range
    });
    console.log((!eventsInRange && smallestDate < start && biggestDate > end) )
    return (!eventsInRange && smallestDate < start && biggestDate > end) 
  }
```

Comment: oh really? , still learning though, do you have good recommendations for calendar plugin?

Comment: I don't have any recommendations, it's just my feeling. If I would have a problem of such, then I will probably look for some solution out there that is faster or write some on my own. But if fullcalendar fit your needs then you are good to go :) It all depends on situation- for me it is just too heavy and written in rather old manner.

Comment: @Chrissa if you think this answer is useful, please accept it, thanks